# Warning inside code when updating Parse object

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using the following code to update a Parse object as button action:

```
-(IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender
{


    NSLog(@"boton subir cadena pulsado");
    loadingSpinner.hidden = NO;
    [loadingSpinner startAnimating];

    //Upload a new picture
    NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.chainPhoto.image);

    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"img" data:pictureData];
    [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if (succeeded){
            NSLog(@"IMAGEN CARGADA");

            PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"cadenas"];

            // Retrieve the object by id
            [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId: chain.objectId block:^(PFObject *imageObject, NSError *error)
             {

            [imageObject setObject:file forKey:@"image"];




            [imageObject setObject:self.commentTextField.text forKey:@"chain_name"];


            [imageObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                if (succeeded){
                    //Go back to the wall
                    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
                else{
                    NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
                    [self showErrorView:errorString];
                }
            }];
        }

       ERROR HERE--> else
            {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            [self showErrorView:errorString];
        }

             }
        [loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
        //loadingSpinner.hidden = YES;
        //self.commentTextField.text =@" ";
        self.progress_block.hidden = YES;

       // self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.jpg"];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restaurant Chain changed with success"
                                                        message:@"You can now go back to the list."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];



    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {


        self.progress_block.hidden =NO;
        self.progress_block.progress = (float) percentDone/100+progressValue;


    }];

}
```

In the line that I have marked as ERROR HERE in the code, there is an error warning (Expected ":"), but I can't find out why.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you never closed the query bracket:

```
PFQuery getObjectInBackground.... {
```

but never closed it using the proper syntax or it looks like you have an extra bracket `}`. For better practice, you should use proper indentation with if statements or else complications can happen like this. You get lost in the code because you don't know where a statement begins or ends

You should close it after the else statement so:

```
    } ERROR HERE--> else {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        [self showErrorView:errorString];
        //stop animating and other stuff
    }
}];
```

I can't troubleshoot because i'm on my iPhone but I would suggest going back and using proper indentation so you can catch your culprit

Comment: Thank you, I have reinvented the code and corrected it following your proposal.

Comment: @mvasco okay cool, yeah it's always best to keep indentation proper, not for that, because what happens when go back to that code a year from now, you want it to be clear and concise because at that point it will be alien to you.